# Custom checkbox image - but can still see original?

Tags: android, checkbox

I was using the standard Android checkbox, but when I installed my app on other peoples phones for testing, the checkbox was different on each phone.

On one of the phones, the checkbox was so light you could hardly see the box when it was checked.

So I tried to make a custom checkbox checked image.

This worked ok, but I can still see the original deafult checkbox image in the background?

Any ideas why?

Here is my checkable linear layout, to be honest I'm not even sure if I need this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.myapp.myappname.CheckableLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:background="@drawable/customcheckbox"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</com.myapp.myappname.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

Then I have a custom list row which is my custom ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.myapp.myappname.CheckableLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

 <!-- File Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Some Text." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:enabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
 </com.myapp.myappname.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

Any ideas how to suppress the original?

Custom checkbox:

```
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />-->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" /> &lt;!&ndash; default &ndash;&gt;-->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you want to change is `button`, not `background`.

First, design your custom graphics for different button states. Use a state list drawable ([docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)) to associate the various images. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Save this into your drawable resources folder, something like my_checkbox.xml.

Now, use the button attribute on your checkbox layout definition:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

Comment: This worked but for some reason if I click my list row, the checkbox custom checked image does not appear until I scroll that row 'off' the screen, then when I scroll back - its there.  Any ideas?  I've added my custom checkbox xml

Comment: This is what happens when the custom List row is pressed by the user:                       CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                            cb.performClick();

Comment: This is just a guess, but you might need more drawable states for your checkbox to display correctly. I would at least include a checked image and an unchecked image, if not a focused one as well.

Comment: Thanks - I think it was due to the fact that I was using the checkbox.perform click.  I removed the above lines and I added a method to my custom adapter and used notifydatasetchanged in there.  Seems to work well now. Many Thanks for your help it was a good spot!